# How to display 2 cards on each row?

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, flexbox

I have 5 cards in a container and I'm trying to display two cards on each row. I tried the below code but its giving one card on each row. How to solve this issue?

**HTML**

```
  <div id="cards-container">
    <ion-card>
      <ion-img src="../../../../../../assets/sample.jpg"></ion-img>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-img src="../../../../../../assets/sample.jpg"></ion-img>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-img src="../../../../../../assets/sample.jpg"></ion-img>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-img src="../../../../../../assets/sample.jpg"></ion-img>
    </ion-card>
    <ion-card>
      <ion-img src="../../../../../../assets/sample.jpg"></ion-img>
    </ion-card>
  </div>
```

**SCSS**

```
#cards-container {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;

  ion-card {
    margin: 5px;
    width: 50%;
  }
}
```

Comment: If you use ionic framework, why not use the ionic grid for that? https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/grid

Comment: I tried that but I'm rendering cards with for loop that means cards at index 0 and 1 should be at row 0 and index 2 and 3 should be at row 1. I have to build logic for this and flex was lot easier because it was directly wrapping cards so I don't need to build any logic, single for loop is enough. But than also if you have any easier solution with ion-grid tell me I'll think of implementing it.

Comment: Which ionic version are you using?

Comment: @huanfeng Latest version.

Comment: Latest Version should work as your requirement. No dont need to make any logic for this. it should work like this. If you are facing any issue let us know with code sample.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Template:

```
<div id="cards-container">
  <ion-card>
    <ion-img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></ion-img>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></ion-img>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></ion-img>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></ion-img>
  </ion-card>
  <ion-card>
    <ion-img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></ion-img>
  </ion-card>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
#cards-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;

  ion-card {
    margin: 5px 0;
    width: calc(50% - 15px);
  }
}
```

Comment: What if I want some margin of 5px and width can be smaller according to that?

Comment: Yes, you can try to control it by yourself. I'll help you if you still have this kind of question tomorrow :)

Comment: How to control that?

Comment: See the updated answer, using calc(50% - 10px) should be control easily.

Comment: yes it worked perfectly. But the cards are not spaced evenly. The gap between cards is double the gap between boundary and card. Is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Please see my updated styles, it's should be a simple math solution.

Comment: Have you ever checked the latest update? It should solve the question.

Comment: I'm sorry I'm little busy. I'll check it soon and will let you know.

Comment: Top margin of cards in first row is lesser than expected and if there's one card in last row than its justified in center. Is it possible to equalise all margins and last card should be placed in first column instead of center?

Answer (score 0):

add `flex-direction: row;` and remove `margin: 5px;`. You can use `flex-basis` instead of 'width' of child

```css
#cards-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly; //give flex-start to align items to the left of flexbox

}
div {
  // margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: 50%;
}

img{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="cards-container">
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/100/500/300"/>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Still there's one card on each row and that card is justified in center of row.

Comment: @MayankKataria could you please look at the edited code and try to reproduce the same for your code as well.

Comment: I don't want the effect as shown in snippet.